# coupon collector's problem - labelled or not?

Tags: combinatorics, coupon-collector-problem

I have come across the famous [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem).

Linking the problem to the [Twelvefold way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way), my first reaction has been to use the case with `unlabelled balls with labelled boxes`. However, it seems that the question is answered typically (correctly?) with `labelled balls with labelled boxes` case. Please see this question [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26528/m-balls-n-boxes-probability-problem) for the approaches.

So I wonder why this is the case.

Comment: Try: http://math.stackexchange.com/ (Combinatorics problems like these are much more popular over there).

Comment: Also, is it the basic version of the question (i.e. expected number of draws to collect all "N" coupons) or what?